# how to rename a group and a directory correctly in xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, xcode4.2, xcode4.5

Basically I have all the .h and .m files under "Classes" directory as well as the "Classes" group. Then I regret on giving such a name, so I changed the directory to "src" using "mv" command line and then removed "Classes" group and dragged "src" back in. Then when i run my code, I got a sigabrt error immediately. Anyone knows why? I tried reopen xcode project, which doesn't fix it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of Xcode?  Classes seems to be a standard name used by many, however I use the name "Source" and for big projects I create sub-groups within that.

Comment: Xcode is Version 4.6 (4H127). I had to rename it since I didn't realize the "Classes" is actually a well known name. I actually closed xcode and manually modified the .pbxproject file and it worked..

Comment: what gave me headeache was "I renamed the physical folder on my mac; then i removed the Classes group and dragged in the folder from Finder" then when i run XCode, it gave me a sigabrt...I hate sigabrt...glad that i finally fixed it. But wasted so much of my time. Sometimes, i even need to close and reopen xcode for things it cannot pick up. it's just so annoying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do this once for 117 source files that I wanted to organize differently. 
Here is what I did:

1. Delete all source files and groups from the project (remove reference) and quit Xcode.
2. Go look at your files in the finder, create some new folders and move the source files as you see fit.
3. Back into Xcode, drag the root folder of your new source file hierarchy in the project file list. Xcode will create group folders for any subfolder you created, thus matching exactly your hierarchy on disk (there is an option for that in the import dialog). Don't forget to check that the imported files are added to your target (again in the import dialog box).

Your project should then compile as before.
There are other ways to achieve this, but I found this method to be the most efficient.